# How do I stop by my chat popup from window opening to new page?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to embed a chat window popup on my page after a timer goes off, but for some reason when the chat popup is initialized it ends up creating a whole new page with only the chat window.

I printed "TESTING" initially to test what happens to the the "TESTING" text after the timer goes off and it just disappears.

```
<script language="javascript" src=""></script> 
<script language="javascript">
document.write("TESTING");

setTimeout(function chat() {
init_url="url name"
init_host="hostname"; 
init_fullscreen_text="FullScreen"; 
init_fullscreen_url=""; 
init_position=POSITION_BOTTOM_RIGHT; 
init_maximize=MAXIMIZE; 
init_width="202";
init_height="318";
showCWindow();},(8000));

</script>
```

So how do I keep my popup from creating a new page, and just keep it on the same page?

Comment: You should post your `showCWindow()` function too.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `document.write` for debugging. Matter of fact - don't use it for anything - it's evil. Use `console.log()` if needed.